# Log Retention for Aurora Serverless in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-aurora-serverless

I have a Aurora Cluster (Serverless - PostgreSQL) setup in CloudFormation and I want to configure the Log Retention to be around 7 days but I haven't been able to find where to set this setting.

This is my CloudFormation definition for the DBCluster:

```
AuroraDBCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineMode: serverless
      EngineVersion: 10.7
      DatabaseName: test-db
      DeletionProtection: false
      ScalingConfiguration:
        AutoPause: True
        MaxCapacity: 8
        MinCapacity: 2
        SecondsUntilAutoPause: 300
      VpcSecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref AuroraClusterSecurityGroup
      Port: !Ref DBPort
      MasterUsername:
        !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref AuroraMasterSecret, ':SecretString:username}}' ]]
      MasterUserPassword:
        !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref AuroraMasterSecret, ':SecretString:password}}' ]]
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup      
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 35
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref RDSDBClusterParameterGroup
      StorageEncrypted: true
      KmsKeyId: !Ref AuroraKMSCMK
```

I have created a different LogGroup like this:

```
  AuroraClusterLogGroup:
    Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
    Properties:
      RetentionInDays: 7
      LogGroupName: !Join ["", ["/aws/rds/cluster/", !Ref AuroraDBCluster, /postgresql]]
```

But when I deploy the stack, it says:

```
CREATE_FAILED  AWS::Logs::LogGroup  AuroraClusterLogGroup  /aws/rds/cluster/aurora-serverless-db-ufeihfhef74465/postgresql already exists
```

Because (I think) the AuroraDBCluster resource creates its own LogGroup with the same name.

I have reviewed the `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` documentation but I have not found any references for the Log Retention.

What can I do in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Aurora has already created its own log group, you **can't change it from CloudFormation**. The only way to do this would be use [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in your template.

In the custom resource you could use [put-retention-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-retention-policy.html) to modify the retention time of chosen log group.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this limitation myself by following advice https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/190#issuecomment-1318541109

> 1. Extract ClusterIdentifier as parameter, So you can create LogGroup first by using Dependson Here is an example stack
>    Cons: You will need to use new parameter value whenever you are modifying any DBCluster parameter that require replacement otherwise stack update will fail.

```yaml
Parameters:
  ClusterId:
    Type: string

Resources:
  DBCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    DependsOn: DBClusterLogGroupError
    Properties:
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref ClusterId
      DatabaseName: foo
      Engine        : aurora
      EngineMode    : serverless
      EngineVersion : 5.6.10a
      MasterUsername: testuser
      MasterUserPassword: testpassword

  DBClusterLogGroupError:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/rds/cluster/${ClusterId}/error
      RetentionInDays: 90
```

---

You mention,

> But when I deploy the stack, it says:
>
> ```
> CREATE_FAILED  AWS::Logs::LogGroup  AuroraClusterLogGroup  /aws/rds/cluster/aurora-serverless-db-ufeihfhef74465/postgresql already exists
> ```

Assuming you implement the suggestion I provided above, you can work around the issue by manually deleting the log in CloudWatch. Then run this new template. It will then be re-created, but this time by CloudFormation itself.